# Enter file in which to save the key

Tags: ssh

When generating an SSH key with OpenBSD, we are asked to enter a file in which to save the key.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/TheUser/.ssh/id_rsa):
```

From reading the [OpenBSD manual pages](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/ssh-keygen.1), I understand that the file we enter will store the *private* key and another file with a `.pub` extension will store the *public* key.

> Normally this program generates the key and asks for a file in which to store the private key. The public key is stored in a file with the same name but “.pub” appended.

The [GitHub pages on Generating SSH Keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) says that we should just press enter to continue here. My sense is that means we'll just use a default file, which I assume is in the parentheses, for example: `(/c/Users/TheUser/.ssh/id_rsa)`.

Is what I wrote above correct? Also, what are the implications of actually entering a file in which to save the key rather than just pressing enter as GitHub suggests? While I'm pretty sure that `id_rsa` is just the default, and that it can be anything, I would like to know the conventions.

Answer (score 9):

If you use a non default file name, you have to tell ssh to use this keyfile.

For example by adding to your .ssh/config

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/yourcustomfilename
```

or by using

```
# ssh -i ~/.ssh/yourcustomfilename
```

Answer (score 2):

when you enter a filename(for exsample: `/e/myproject/.ssh/myssh`), the created SSH Key will be stored in `/e/myproject/.ssh/` with name `myssh` and `myssh.pub`